# Protractor cannot get the text value

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine

I am trying to get the value of the element. But my console.log is giving something like this

```
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
{ ptor_:
   { controlFlow: [Function],
     schedule: [Function],
     setFileDetector: [Function],
     getSession: [Function],
     getCapabilities: [Function],
     quit: [Function],
     actions: [Function],
     touchActions: [Function],
     executeScript: [Function],
     executeAsyncScript: [Function],
     call: [Function],
     wait: [Function],
     sleep: [Function],
     getWindowHandle: [Function],
     getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
     getPageSource: [Function],
     close: [Function],
     getCurrentUrl: [Function],
     getTitle: [Function],
     findElementInternal_: [Function],
     findDomElement_: [Function],
     findElementsInternal_: [Function],
     takeScreenshot: [Function],
     manage: [Function],
     switchTo: [Function],
     driver:
      { session_: [Object],
        executor_: [Object],
        flow_: [Object],
        fileDetector_: null },
     element: { [Function] all: [Function] },
     '$': [Function],
     '$$': [Function],
     baseUrl: '',
     rootEl: 'body',
     ignoreSynchronization: true,
     getPageTimeout: 10000,
     params: {},
     ready:
      { closure_uid_676969452: 12,
        flow_: [Object],
        stack_: null,
        parent_: null,
        callbacks_: null,
        state_: 'fulfilled',
        handled_: true,
        value_: null,
        queue_: null },
     plugins_:
      { pluginConfs: [],
        pluginObjs: [],
        assertions: {},
        resultsReported: false },
     resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>',
     trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true,
     mockModules_: [ [Object] ],
     allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
     getProcessedConfig: [Function],
     forkNewDriverInstance: [Function],
     restart: [Function] },
  parentElementArrayFinder:
   { ptor_:
      { controlFlow: [Function],
        schedule: [Function],
        setFileDetector: [Function],
        getSession: [Function],
        getCapabilities: [Function],
        quit: [Function],
        actions: [Function],
        touchActions: [Function],
        executeScript: [Function],
        executeAsyncScript: [Function],
        call: [Function],
        wait: [Function],
        sleep: [Function],
        getWindowHandle: [Function],
        getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
        getPageSource: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        getCurrentUrl: [Function],
        getTitle: [Function],
        findElementInternal_: [Function],
        findDomElement_: [Function],
        findElementsInternal_: [Function],
        takeScreenshot: [Function],
        manage: [Function],
        switchTo: [Function],
        driver: [Object],
        element: [Object],
        '$': [Function],
        '$$': [Function],
        baseUrl: '',
        rootEl: 'body',
        ignoreSynchronization: true,
        getPageTimeout: 10000,
        params: {},
        ready: [Object],
        plugins_: [Object],
        resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>',
        trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true,
        mockModules_: [Object],
        allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
        getProcessedConfig: [Function],
        forkNewDriverInstance: [Function],
        restart: [Function] },
     getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_:
      { closure_uid_676969452: 253,
        flow_: [Object],
        stack_: null,
        parent_: [Object],
        callbacks_: null,
        state_: 'pending',
        handled_: false,
        value_: undefined,
        queue_: null },
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.top-bar li' } },
  then: [Function],
  elementArrayFinder_:
   { ptor_:
      { controlFlow: [Function],
        schedule: [Function],
        setFileDetector: [Function],
        getSession: [Function],
        getCapabilities: [Function],
        quit: [Function],
        actions: [Function],
        touchActions: [Function],
        executeScript: [Function],
        executeAsyncScript: [Function],
        call: [Function],
        wait: [Function],
        sleep: [Function],
        getWindowHandle: [Function],
        getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
        getPageSource: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        getCurrentUrl: [Function],
        getTitle: [Function],
        findElementInternal_: [Function],
        findDomElement_: [Function],
        findElementsInternal_: [Function],
        takeScreenshot: [Function],
        manage: [Function],
        switchTo: [Function],
        driver: [Object],
        element: [Object],
        '$': [Function],
        '$$': [Function],
        baseUrl: '',
        rootEl: 'body',
        ignoreSynchronization: true,
        getPageTimeout: 10000,
        params: {},
        ready: [Object],
        plugins_: [Object],
        resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>',
        trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true,
        mockModules_: [Object],
        allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
        getProcessedConfig: [Function],
        forkNewDriverInstance: [Function],
        restart: [Function] },
     getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_:
      { closure_uid_676969452: 253,
        flow_: [Object],
        stack_: null,
        parent_: [Object],
        callbacks_: null,
        state_: 'pending',
        handled_: false,
        value_: undefined,
        queue_: null },
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.top-bar li' } } }
```

I have this code

```
it('it should place order', function () {
   browser.get('https://site.loc/index.php?route=account/login');

   element.all(by.css('.top-bar li')).then(function(items) {
         console.log(items[0].getText());
   });
});
```

here is my html

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="https://site.loc/index.php?route=account/logout">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://site.loc/index.php?route=account/account">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://site.loc/index.php?route=account/wishlist" id="wishlist-total">Wish List (1)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://site.loc/index.php?route=checkout/cart">Shopping Cart</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://site.loc/index.php?route=checkout/checkout">Checkout</a></li>
</ul>
```

The reason I want in that on the basis of what I get I want to make cetrain decisions. I know I can do something like this

```
expect(items.length).toBe(3)
```

but that does not help me as I am looking for a specific thing and then do some more decisions based on that

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) returns a promise. You would need something like

```
items[0].getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

or, if you're a fan of brevity

```
items[0].getText().then(console.log.bind(console));
```

---

If you're interested in logging each element and its text, see [`ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each)

```
element.all(by.css('.top-bar li')).each(function(element, index) {
    element.getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(index, text);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks just one thing..items[0] ...is there a wayt to get the index in there?

Comment: @Autolycus in where? You might be interested in the manual page for [`ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each)

Comment: element.all(by.css('.top-bar li')).then(function(items) {
         items[0].getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
   }); so that I can get mutliple    items[i].getText().

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Phil

Answer (score 2):

What you see on the console is a *promise*, returned by `getText()`. If you want to see the real text value, you would need to *explicitly resolve this promise*:

```
element.all(by.css('.top-bar li')).then(function(items) {
    items[0].getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
});
```

---

But, if you need to assert the text of an element, you can pass the `getText()` directly into `expect()` - in Protractor, *it is patched to understand promises*:

```
expect(elm.getText()).toEqual('Logout');
```

If you need to get the first element from an array of elements, you can use [`.first()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first):

```
var items = element.all(by.css('.top-bar li'));
expect(items.first().getText()).toEqual('Logout');
```

And, by the way, note that you can call `getText()` on an array of elements:

```
expect(items.getText()).toEqual(["Logout", "My Account", ... ]);
```

To check the count of items - use [`.count()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count):

```
expect(items.count()).toEqual(3);
```

Comment: Thank you...Excellent information. I voted your answer up but since already had the answer, I accepted his. Yours help greatly as well....too bad you cant have 2 accepted answers :D

Comment: @Autolycus this is not a problem at all. What is important is that your problem is resolved and we all may be helped others who would have similar issues in the future. Thanks!